# How do I cross-compile a Go program on a Mac for Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, go, cross-compiling

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ sudo ./myprogram 
./myprogram: 1: ./myprogram: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I found out this happens when I do not generate the binary file from the same OS. I do `go build` with Mac OS but I need to run this binary from Vagrant that uses Ubuntu Linux. What command should I use instead of `go build` from Mac so that I can run the binary program in Vagrant environment?

Comment: And again, please consider forgetting about the fact you're using Vagrant: it's just a means to allow you running a *foreign OS* on your "native" OS, and hence it has absolutely nothing to do neither with the guest OS nor with Go programs running there. You had to tell us something like "how do I build Go program on a Mac running Ice Jaguar (x86) for Ubuntu Pompous Pterodactyl (amd64)?" -- something like that. Vagrant does not know anything about Go or compilation or running programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a cross-compilation environment (by building the go compiler yourself). Dave Cheney's blog has good instructions: http://dave.cheney.net/2013/07/09/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go-1-1

Answer (score 9):

Note: with the upcoming Go 1.5 (Q3 2015), this will be easier.

See "[Cross compilation just got a whole lot better in Go 1.5](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/03/03/cross-compilation-just-got-a-whole-lot-better-in-go-1-5)"
(still from [Dave Cheney](http://dave.cheney.net/about))

> For successful cross compilation you would need
>
> - compilers for the target platform, if they differed from your host platform, ie you’re on darwin/amd64 (6g) and you want to compile for linux/arm (5g).
> - a standard library for the target platform, which included some files generated at the point your Go distribution was built.
>
> With the plan to translate the [Go compiler into Go](http://golang.org/s/go13compiler) coming to fruition in the 1.5 release the first issue is now resolved.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "runtime"

func main() {
        fmt.Printf("Hello %s/%s\n", runtime.GOOS, runtime.GOARCH)
}
```

> build for darwin/386

```
% env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=386 go build hello.go
# scp to darwin host
$ ./hello
Hello darwin/386
```

> Or build for linux/arm

```
% env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build hello.go
# scp to linux host
$ ./hello
Hello linux/arm
```