# How do I cross compile my Go program from Mac OS X to Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: linux, macos, go

As the title says I'm wondering how to cross-compile my program so that I can run it on Ubuntu 64-bit

I've went into the `/usr/local/go/src` folder and ran

`GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 ./make.bash --no-clean`

everything compiled fine

then went into my project directory and ran `go build -v -a` and then took the compiled binary and moved it to my linux server, but when running it I get this error:

```
root@PanicCSGO40:~/test# ./test
-bash: ./test: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
root@PanicCSGO40:~/test# sudo ./test
./test: 1: ./test: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
root@PanicCSGO40:~/test#
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong any information would be great thanks.

I've also tried doing it with `GOARCH=386` but still get the same errors. Thanks!

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377271/how-do-i-cross-compile-a-go-program-on-a-mac-for-ubuntu) does not solve my question because the chosen answer is a link to a blog post which relies heavily on doing all cross-compilation on using the blog writers `bash` scripts to do it, I just simply wanted to know what the correct way to do it was and now I do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I cross-compile a Go program on a Mac for Ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377271/how-do-i-cross-compile-a-go-program-on-a-mac-for-ubuntu)

Comment: @Colin Nicholson - Similar problem as that question, but different solution due to changes in the Go toolchain.  The process is much simpler with Go 1.5.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The build command needs to identify the target environment:

```
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -v /path/to/target/package
```